# Adding Links to Nodes in D3

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

So I'm dealing with a problem in my d3 visual in which I'm trying to create nodes which have clickable links to them. I'm just learning d3 so I was having trouble creating these links. Now so far i've gotten links on all the nodes but I want to achieve essentially is to have different links for each node. Currently I just put in a url for every single node but how would i select an individual node and attach a link to it. I want to have it so when a user clicks the object node it goes to another page.

```
var onode = svg.append('g').selectAll(".outer_node")
        .data(data.outer)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "outer_node")
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", click);

function click (d){
    window.open("https://www.google.com", "_self");
    }
```

This makes it so each node has the same exact link, i didn't know exactly how to assign different links. Can someone please help?

Comment: I believe that by passing in the d in the function click, i am effectively on the current node in the group? Is this true? If so then how would could i assign links based on the position in the array. Sorry just very confused how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have URLs stored in the dataset, the you can access the URL in your function:

```
function click (d){
    let url = "http://" + d.url; //or whatever your URL field is called in the data
    window.open(url, "_self");
}
```

You mention "position in the array", so if the URLs are in separate array, but which align with the dataset, then you could use

```
function click (d, i){ //is this 0 based index of each item in the selection
    let url = urlData[i]
    window.open(url, "_self");
 }
```